# Laravel post submit not working in production but works in local development

Tags: laravel, post, service, production

I tried searching and messing around myself for several hours w/o success, so here I am.

Here is my simplified controller:

```
class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    protected $emailService;
    protected $prospectEmailService;

    public function __construct(EmailServiceInterface $emailService, ProspectEmailServiceInterface $prospectEmailService) {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->emailService = $emailService;
        $this->prospectEmailService = $prospectEmailService;
    }
    public function pEmails(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('get'))
        {
            // do something and load a view - get specific view
        }
        elseif ($request->isMethod('post')
        {
            // do something and load a post specific view
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when the get view is loaded and I submit a form, the get page gets loaded again as if post is not submitted or working. I did some testing and found out that after submit, code execution did not even enter the elseif block.

In addition,

1. the code works perfectly find in local dev environment.
2. Other controllers can do post w/o problem. Other controllers does not    inject service obj in __construct.
3. I looked into log file, and it doesn't contain anything regarding
   this. log level set to debug.

Can someone please enlighten me on where I should look???

front end code:

```
@extends('layouts.content')
@section('title', 'Prospects Email Settings')

@section('content')
    <div id='content'>
        <h2>Prospects Email Settings</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Note:</p>


            <h4>Current effective settings: </h4>
            <p>Schedule start date and time: {{ $currentSetting->start_dt }} </p>
            <p>Sending interval: {{ $currentSetting->span }} days</p>
            <p>Email sequence: {{ $currentSetting->email_sequence }}</p>

            <form action='/settings/prospectsEmails/' method='post'> 
                {{ csrf_field() }}      

                <h4>Create new prospects email settings below:</h4>
                <label>Schedule starting date and time: </label>
                <input type='datetime-local' name='startdt'>
                <br><br>
                <label>Sending interval (days): </label>
                <select name='interval'>
                    <option value="7">1 week</option>
                    <option value="14">2 weeks</option>
                    <option value="21">3 weeks</option>
                    <option value="28">4 weeks</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label>Specify email sequence</label>
                <br><br>
                <div>
                    @for ($i = 1; $i < 16; $i++)
                        <label>Email {{$i}}:</label>
                        <select name="email_{{ $i }}">
                            <option value="0">---</option>
                            @foreach ($emails as $email)
                                <option value="{{ $email->Email_ID }}">{{ $email->Email_ID }}: {{ $email->subject }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <br><br>
                    @endfor
                </div>
                <label>Schedule the first email right away:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="start_schedule" value="yes"> Yes
                <input type="radio" name="start_schedule" value="no" checked="checked"> No
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Create/update Email Sequence" />
                <br><br>
            </form>

            @if ($method == 'post')
                <h3>{{ $msg }}<h3>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: In your testing, did the pEmails function get called at all? Could you possibly post the front end side of this; the view.

Comment: Please show use your routes/web.php file.

Comment: I see two typos here `elseif ($request->isMethod('post')`: space between else and if, and need to close the condition block. Is this a typo in the code or a typo while posting? :)

Comment: to Chris Cousins: Yes, I am sure the pEmails get called in the get block. I tested it with returning a simple get view. The problem is when a form submitted, the code in the elseif block never gets called.

Comment: the front end code:

Comment: to Jamesking56: the route related to the controller: Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'settings/prospectsEmails', 'SettingsController@pEmails');

Comment: To Paras: pretty sure it is not because of elseif vs else if or closing the condition block. The same code was used in another controller and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure now about the reason causing all this.

It has something to do with the use of "/" in routes and uri.

Because of not following a restrict rule of using "/", some of my uri has "/" at the end and some does not. Eventually cause a mess at some places.

Right now, to make it work, my uri always starts with "/" and ending without "/'.